# How to understand the gadlus of Taanoim?

Tags: talmud-gemara

How might we gain insight into the intellectual and spiritual gadlus of the Taanoim , as well as their perception of the world, considering the historical context and the diverse range of their writings?
How did the Taanoim perceive the world, taking into account the depth of their Torah knowledge and the breadth of their exposure to various disciplines and perspectives?

Comment: You might enjoy this set https://korenpub.com/collections/rabbi-binyamin-lau/products/sages-set

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Your question might be closed for being too broad - but hopefully this won't deter you from coming back. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: And let's not assume "the Tannaim" are a monolith...

Comment: As it stands, this is not really a good question for MiYodeya, but you can rephrase it to ask for book recommendations or something like that. I have a few recommendations of my own